# To a Pathological End

Tags: phrases, expressions

What does the phrase "to a pathological end" mean in this sentence?

(Sentence)
This is the same reason why most of us like them to a pathological end.

(My research)

pathological : not reasonable or sensible

end : purpose

So I am guessing the meaning of this sentence is as follows:
This is the same reason why most of us like them for a reason which is not reasonable for other people.

if my guess is correct, is there any difference between the nuance of the two sentences. For example, is the phrase "To a pathological end" too formal to use in a conversation?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: I am sorry. I added my research below the sentence. I am a super novice in this English forum. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: The principle meaning of "pathological" is "caused by disease" or "markedly abnormal".

Comment: @masa ~ I must say I was confused until I read it all the way through. Now it makes perfect sense. But I agree that it might be too formal for most people. Like me, they'd have to think about it before they realized it's metaphorical.

Comment: It might be more easily understood if it finished *"... to a pathological extent"* describing how much we like them

Comment: I thought the word "end" and "extent" were exchangeable too, but I didn't see a close meaning to "extent" in the definitions of "end"...(Maybe my dictionary is not that good.). If I switch "end" to "extent", I think that the meaning of the sentence would be  "we like them to the point where people find the way we like them abnormal". But if I interpret "end" as "purpose", the meaning would be "we like them for a reason which people find abnormal." I am wondering which one is closer to the meaning the original sentence is trying to mean.

Comment: It sounds like the claim is about liking "them" even though it eventually harms the ones doing the 'liking'. It might become clearer if you add more context - say, extend the quote to a paragraph or two. This would help to establish what the author had in mind.

Comment: I have run into this phrase several times, but this paragraph triggered me into asking the question. [paragraph] The man is using (and maintaining) the text editor he used for more than quarter of a century. It is difficult to say why, given the host of newer, more efficient text editors. He is probably used to the shortcuts and he knows his way around the editor, which is an important feature that will increase his efficiency. This is the same reason why most of us like Vim or Emacs or Nano to a pathological end. [end]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of this is that "to what end" means "for what purpose" or "for what outcome".  Thus the sentence means that we like them (perhaps the reason is that they make us feel good) and, in the end, they make us sick.  (For example, cigarettes.)

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to_what_end:

For what purpose

We will never know to what ends he was working.
   To what end are you spending so much time reading the newspaper?
   They put so much effort into it, but to what end?